# Clicking the gridview column header whole gridview tries to cover the window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, gridview

I am sorting a GridView by clicking on the column header. However, when I add more items to the gridview and it becomes scrollable, clicking the column header for the first time does not sort the items. Instead, it moves the gridview upwards and tries the display all the items in the space available.

Is there some property i have to set to prevent this? Here is the code for the GridView:

```
<Window x:Class="AutomatedExitStrategy.Presentation.View.AutomatedExitStrategyShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Automated Exit Strategy System" Height="480" 
    Width="2125">

<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid Opacity="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.20*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.80*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Margin="0,2,0,0" 
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding GlobalRowsCollection}"
            AlternationCount="2">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn
                        Width="25">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Command="{Binding SortList}" CommandParameter="IsEnabled"></GridViewColumnHeader>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Margin="0"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn 
                        Width="Auto">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Command="{Binding SortList}" CommandParameter="InputViewModel.Group">Grp</GridViewColumnHeader>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding InputViewModel.Group}" 
                                               Style="{StaticResource GridBlockStyle}"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the ModelView code and the Window code (if such exists) so the problem can be tested ?

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to the `RequestBringIntoView` event of the ListView and mark it as Handled.

That should prevent the ScrollViewer from scrolling down to try and display the whole ListView, when clicked. And consequently, it should allow the MouseDown event to keep going and trigger the sort.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" 
          Margin="0,2,0,0" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding GlobalRowsCollection}"
          AlternationCount="2"
          RequestBringIntoView="ListView_RequestBringIntoView">
    ...
</ListView>
```

And on the code-behind...

```
public void ListView_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```